# Why is there still blank spaces on str.strip Panda?

Tags: python, pandas

I extract data from sql and convert it to dataframe
I noticed some columns have spaces in the end
Tried to use str.strip but is not working., I still see spaces on each row in my column

Example (assume underline is the spaces)
I also check datatype and it is object
Whats wrong in my code?

RJSCTP
1 xx____
2 bb____

```
df3= pd.read_sql(sqlISNMSDP,conn)
#df3.columns = df3.columns.str.strip()
#df3.columns.str.strip()
df3['RJSCTP'].str.rstrip()
df3['RJSCID'].str.rstrip()
df3.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='ISNMSDP',index=False)
```

Comment: you need to save back: `df3['RJSCTP'] = df3['RJSCTP'].str.rstrip()` and `df3['RJSCID'] = df3['RJSCID'].str.rstrip()`

Comment: This one worked. any reason why my previous code failed?

Comment: Also what if i need to apply it for all columns just to make sure each do not have unnecessary spaces?

Comment: to do it for the whole `df`, i would suggest `applymap` instead: `df = df.applymap(str.rstrip)` (assuming the whole `df` contains strings)

Comment: or if there are also numeric cols, something like: `cols = df.select_dtypes('object').columns; df[cols] = df[cols].applymap(str.rstrip)`